# Creating annotation boxes for subplots in a for-loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, annotations, matlab-figure, subplot

I have the following code in Matlab that runs through a for loop, reads data from a file and plots 9 different figures, that correspond to some particular "channels" in my data, so I decided to annotate them in the for loop.

```
 clear
 clc

 for i=1:9
 subplot(3,3,i);
hold on
x = [4 13];  % from your example
y = ([1 1]);    % from your example
y2 = ([-0.4 -0.4]);
H=area(x,y,'LineStyle','none',...
'FaceColor',[1 0.949019610881805 0.866666674613953]);
H1=area(x,y2,'LineStyle','none',...
'FaceColor',[1 0.949019610881805 0.866666674613953]);
% Create textbox
annotation('textbox',...
[0.719849840255583 0.603626943005185 0.176316293929713 0.308290155440411],...
'String',{'FABLIGHT04','Channel',i},...
'FontWeight','bold',...
'FontSize',10,...
'FontName','Geneva',...
'FitBoxToText','off',...
'EdgeColor','none');
axis([0 24 -0.4 1])
set(gca,'XTick',[0:1:24])
set(gca,'YTick',[-0.4:0.2:1])
xlabel('Time (s)');



 end
```

Initially it was giving me 9 different figures and the annotation thing worked fine. But I wanted to be able to tile them onto a subplot for easier comparison.

Since I switched over to using subplot, it does not annotate my figure properly. On opening the editing dock and generating the code, I find that matlab is plotting everything first and then just putting the annotation boxes in the same figure, one on top of the other. Looking at the code it generated, it apparently takes this part of the code:

```
 annotation('textbox',...
[0.719849840255583 0.603626943005185 0.176316293929713 0.308290155440411],...
'String',{'FABLIGHT04','Channel',i},...
'FontWeight','bold',...
'FontSize',10,...
'FontName','Geneva',...
'FitBoxToText','off',...
'EdgeColor','none');
```

and does it as:

```
annotation(figure1,'textbox'...)
etc etc
```

So for all 9 text boxes, it puts them onto the same figure. I tried to do `S=subplot(3,3,i)` then `annotation(S,'textbox') etc etc`, I have also tried `S(i)=subplot(3,3,i)` and then `annotation(S,'textbox') etc etc` but nothing seems to work.

I have also tried to change the location of the box. I can't seem to figure out how to make it smaller either.

Does anyone know how to have annotation boxes in the right subplot in a for loop?

Thanks

Comment: can you post a small dataset that we can use to reproduce the error? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I've changed the code now so that you don't need the file I was using. So you should be able to reproduce the error now.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid annotation objects are properties of `figures` and NOT `axes`, as such its harder to customize the position of each annotation objects because no matter how many subplots you have, they are all part of the same figure and you need to specify their position relatively to the figure coordinate system.

Therefore, you can manually set the position of each text box in your code depending on the subplot it belongs to...

Simple example:

```
clear
clc
close all

figure('Units','normalized'); %// new figure window

for k = 1:2

    str = sprintf('Subplot %d',k);

    subplot(1,2,k)

    plot(rand(1,10));

    %// Customize position here
    hAnnot(k) = annotation('textbox', [k*.4-.2 .6 .1 .1],...
        'String', str,'FontSize',14);

end
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Its not very elegant but I'm personally not aware of any other option if you do need to use annotations objects. A less cumbersome alternative would be to use a simple [text](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) objects, which are properties of axes and therefore much more friendly to position :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah looking around for something on it, I realised it might be the case. Thanks a lot for your solution, it works perfectly!